# uwp get position in grid by clicking a cell

Tags: grid, win-universal-app

I have a grid with all empty cells, now I want to get the coordinate when user clicking on the screen. How do I know which cell was clicked and cell position?
Please help me

```
        gameboard.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        gameboard.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        gameboard.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
        gameboard.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;

        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            var cd = new ColumnDefinition();
            cd.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
            var rd = new RowDefinition();
            rd.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
            gameboard.ColumnDefinitions.Add(cd);
            gameboard.RowDefinitions.Add(rd);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
            {
                Border border = new Border();
                border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
                border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
                border.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
                border.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
                Grid.SetColumn(border, j);
                Grid.SetRow(border, k);
                gameboard.Children.Add(border);
            }
        }
        canvas2.Children.Add(gameboard);
```

Comment: Can you provide your `xaml` code?

Comment: sry, I created grid in code behind, so there is nothing in xaml. Here is my cs code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, setup `Background` to your `Border` for handling `Tap` event:

```
border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
border.Tapped += Border_Tapped;
```

To getting position of your `Border` element you can use two ways:

- Retrieve `Column` and `Row` indexes of your `Grid`
- Retrieve point position relative to `UIElement` (e.g.: `Window.Current.Content`)

  ```
  private void Border_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      // First way:
      var border = (Border)sender;
      var column = Grid.GetColumn(border);
      var row = Grid.GetRow(border);

      // Second way
      var point = e.GetPosition(Window.Current.Content);
  }
  ```